# Can't add a task when another instance of outlook is running

Tags: windows-services, mapi, outlook-redemption

I try to add a task/appointment to outlook from windows service. I'm using such code to do this:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();

session.Logon();

RDOAppointmentItem appo = (RDOAppointmentItem)session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Add();

appo.Subject = lessons[i].Type;
appo.Start = lessons[i].Start;
appo.End = lessons[i].End;
appo.Save();
session.Logoff();
```

Everything works fine when another instance of outlook isn't running. But when it is I get such error:

```
Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER
ulVersion: 0
Error: Nie mo¿na otworzyæ (Can't open file) C:\Users\d3dek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst.
Component: Foldery osobiste (Personal folders)
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 268828930
```

My windows service is working on user 'd3dek'. Any ideas? I read that pst folders can work with multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

If your service and Outlook are running in diffeeren security contexts, the PST provider cannot share the PST file between different processes.
What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Outlook 2007 (12.0.4518.1014) MSO (12.0.4518.1014). How to select such security context, can I do it with redemption?

Comment: If Outlook running with elevated priviledges? Is UAC on? What service identity does your service use?